# Need for SqlConnection and OracleConnection, if OdbcConnection can be used in these places

Tags: c#, oracle, sqlconnection, dbconnection

In the journey of creating common `DAL` for connecting to `Sql Server` and `Oracle`. After some implementations, I ended with a confusion if `OdbcConnection` can be used for connecting to both `Database`, Why there is need for specific implementations like `SqlConnection` and `OracleConnection`.

1. Which will be the suggested way of implementation?
2. Please advise Pros and Cons for specific implementation

**Interfaces**

```
public interface IDatabaseFactory  
{
   DbConnection GetConnection();

   DbCommand CreateCommand();

   IDbParameter CreateParameter();
}
```

**Implementations**

```
public class SqlFactory : IDatabaseFactory  
{
   public DbConnection GetConnection(){ return new SqlConnection();}

   public DbCommand CreateCommand(){ return new SqlCommand();}

   public IDbParameter CreateParameter(){ return new SqlParameter();}
}

public class SqlFactory : IDatabaseFactory  
{
   public DbConnection GetConnection(){ return new OracleConnection();}

   public DbCommand CreateCommand(){ return new OracleCommand();}

   public IDbParameter CreateParameter(){ return new OracleParameter();}
}
```

Comment: Both implementations are same. Guessing that's by mistake.

Comment: @nvartak, yes updated... tks...

Answer (score 2):

A ODBC Connection is a very generic provider to connect to a database. For almost every database you will find an ODBC driver, even for simple CSV files.

As drawback ODBC has several limitations (Hambone listed some in his answer) and in many cases the performance is poorer than with native drivers, because ODBC adds an additional layer on top of native drivers. Maybe in your application this performance degradation is not relevant.

Answer (score 1):

Pros of using ODBC:

1. No dependency on third party driver for Oracle within your .NET solution
2. Less code to write (and maintain) in your factories, as they are all using the same classes (System.Data.Odbc)

Cons/considerations of ODBC:

1. If you run this program on multiple machines, the ODBC connections have to be set up the same, whereas if you used Managed ODP.net, you can explicitly define the connection properties in your code
2. In the past, certain ODBC drivers for Oracle have had issues with valid Oracle syntax, such as the `with` clause
3. If you were inclined to use advanced or low-level DBMS-specific features of the database "under the hood" of your factories, such as OCI's bulk inserts/updates (which are AMAZING), ODBC would not give you access to these
4. There may be some datatype confusion with ODBC and certain parameter types.  I can't think of any off the top of my head, but it wouldn't shock me if you encounter a few
5. If you use the `RETURNING` clause, there may be some differences in the implementations (I've never done it in SQL Server, so this is part speculation)

Other considerations:

1. I'm pretty sure that even with ODBC, you will have to manage the way the different systems handle parameters.  For example, Oracle uses `:PARAM` and omits the colon in the `ParameterName` property, whereas SQL Server uses a `@PARAM` and includes the at-sign in the `ParameterName` property
2. I would add a Property for `Transaction` while you're at it

Comment: ODBC for Oracle requires an Oracle Instant Client to be installed. Thus "No dependency on third party driver for Oracle within your .NET solution" is not true (at least for the ODBC driver from Oracle. For the ODBC driver from Microsoft I do not know.)

Comment: Valid point on the dependency, but I was actually referring to a dependency in the .NET application (references).  On the client side, I'm in agreement.  Also, I thought ODBC did support named parameters, but I concede I could be mistaken.  I rarely use ODBC for many of the reasons I listed

Comment: As far as I know parameters in ODBC are always used with `?`, no matter to which RDBMS you are connected (see [Using Oracle ODBC Driver](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b32009/app_odbc.htm) for example). Named parameters are only supported for calls to stored procedures but not in other SQL statements.